# passing data from One Activity to Second Activity when we already using intent for result for getting data of contact,

Tags: android

I am Working on my app, in which I have 2 Activities, In Second activity which has edit text by clicking on it dialog box appear with two buttons ADD FROM CONTACTS(which pick contact from phonebook) and ADD MANUALLY (in this ,manually add no.) and that specific contact or no. will be displayed on edit text, this activity is performing well.Now I want that whatever contact or the no.added in edit text in SECOND ACTIVITY will directly set on textView in FirstActivity.

Comment: You need to post the relevant code because right now this post is pretty unclear and unanswerable

Comment: Google these terms, you will find lots of answers to what you need to do - "passing data between activities bundle"

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(Contact.this, ShowContact.class);
i.putExtra("number", edittextvalue);
```

Here `Contact.this` is the class where you are getting the contact number and `ShowContact.class` is the class where you are showing the contact number.

`edittextvalue` is the number the user input on Contact.class.

***To retrieve the data in ShowClass***, use :

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String number = extras.getString("number");
```

Comment: mark it as right answer and upvote please, if you found it useful.